# ofsteam overwriting the selected part of a txt file

Tags: c++, qt, c++98

I am new in C++98. I am getting some fields from a large text file. I want to update only 4 out of 50 lines in the text file. Here is my code. It is getting the text from a `lineEdit` of a Qt4 form.

```cpp
strcpy(Name,ui->lineEdit_1->setText(QString::fromStdString(Name)) );
strcpy(Class,ui->lineEdit_1->setText(QString::fromStdString(Class)));
strcpy(Grade,ui->lineEdit_1->setText(QString::fromStdString(Grade)));

std::fstream myfile;
myfile.open(mypath,std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out );
myfile<<Name<<"\t"<<"Name"<<"\n";
myfile<<Class<<"\t"<<"Class"<<"\n";
myfile<<Grade<<"\t"<<"Grade"<<"\n";
```

Here is `sample.conf.txt`:

```
Hello.   Name
One.     Class
Two.     Classsec
A+.      Grade
B+.      Gradesec
```

On updating it by adding random values:

```
Name   AA
Class  BB
Grade  CC
```

After executing the above code, it shows this updated `sample.conf.txt`:

```
AA       Name
BB       Class 
CC       Grade
A+.      Grade
B+.      Gradesec
```

It should be like this Model instead:

```
AA       Name
BB.      Class
Two.     Classsec
CC.      Grade
B+.      Gradesec
```

Means it (`fstream`) is just:

1- overwriting truncate the top 3 lines in the file, leaving the rest of the file intact.

2- it is **not** selecting the position field name to overwrite its value, according to input content?

How can I overwrite by selecting the specific position by name and write its corresponding value, or write column-wise? How can I accomplish this task? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. When you update a file, then any text you write will replace exactly the same number of bytes as the size of the text you are writing.

It's not that case that if you write three lines of text, then they will replace the first three lines of text currently in the file (unless those two pieces of text happen to be exactly the same length).

Unless you are doing binary IO with fixed length records then trying to update files is not the way to go. Instead your program should read in the whole file into some data structure, manipulate that data structure as required, and then write out the entire data structure to a file, replacing the whole contents of the file.

Comment: Please suggest c++ data type for such type selective update in txt file?Link for solving this task

Comment: Your file  seems to be a list of pairs of strings, so `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` would be one possibility. But probably it's best to write your own class to represent the pairs of values, and then use a vector of that.

Comment: Alternatively, rather than reading in the whole file at one time, manipulating the data, and then writing out the entire data to file, you could instead read in the input file line-by-line and write out to another output file line-by-line, where you decide whether to keep, modify, or omit each line as needed. When finished, you can replace the input file with the new output file.